# How to repeat but take different inputs each time?

Tags: python, loops, variables, input

```
num = int(input())
for a in range(num):

    a=input()
```

So I want to repeat for how many times num is, but how do you make "a" a different variable? I mean so that there would be many variables a,b,c,d,e...  that are all different user inputs.

Apparently

```
num = int(input())
a = input()
b = input()
c = input()
...
```

Would be too long, and would not match num. So how do I do it?

Comment: You can use a list and push the input values into that, rather than creating dynamic variables